# How to get the http status code of a request with scalajs-angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scala.js

I would like to get the http status code of a request made with scalajs-angular.

I can get it with `http.get[js.Any]("url") success` and a function of type `(js.Any, Int) => Unit`. But I would like to return something else than Unit.

For instance, I would like to be able to do:

```
http.get[js.Any]("url") map {
    case response.status == 200 => true
    case _ => false 
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Fleshing out what I said in the comment below (now that I'm no longer on a phone): based on the docs of scalajs-angular, it looks like its version of `get` returns a version of Promise. What you're looking for is apparently a Future. So I suspect your code will work as intended if you add `.future`, which gets a Future from a Promise:

```
http.get[js.Any]("url").future map {
  case response.status == 200 => true
  case _ => false 
}
```

(NB: I don't use scalajs-angular myself, so this is a guess based on the documentation.)

Comment: I'm aware that get is asynchronous, but I don't understand why I can't get the status of the response since I can get the data of this response. Moreover I can get it when it goes in the recover part: (`recover { case t: HttpException => t.status}`)

Comment: And can you confirm me that you're saying that it is not possible to get the http status returned by a http request as a result (wrapped in a Future) of a function.

Comment: Oh, I see - my apologies, I misunderstood your question.  I haven't used scalajs-angular myself, but from the docs it appears that is version of get returns an HttpPromise, which extends Promise.  Which I believe means you should be able to call .future on that to get a Future, and you should be able to map over that...